# Drag & Drop en TreeTableView

Tags: javafx

Tengo una control `TreeTableView` y quiero arrastrar sus ítems para reordenarlos de forma personalizada y quiero que mientras lo hago se muestre una línea que indique a dónde van a ir. El problema que tengo es que una vez que se dibuja la línea permanece aunque ya no sea válida como si faltase hacer un refresco del contenido del control y no sé como solucionarlo. Dejo aquí un pequeño ejemplo funcional de lo que tengo:

```
package treetableviewdnd;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TreeTableViewDND extends Application {

    private static final DataFormat SERIALIZADO = new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");       
    private TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> raíz;
    private TreeTableView<Map<String, Object>> árbol;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox outer = new VBox();

        raíz = new TreeItem<>();
        árbol = new TreeTableView<>(raíz);
        árbol.setShowRoot(false);
        árbol.setRowFactory(this::rowFactory);
        addColumn("Región", "región");
        addColumn("Población", "población");
        setupData();

        outer.getChildren().addAll(árbol);
        Scene scene = new Scene(outer, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }      

    private TreeTableRow<Map<String, Object>> rowFactory(TreeTableView<Map<String, Object>> view) {
        TreeTableRow<Map<String, Object>> row = new TreeTableRow<>();
        row.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            if (!row.isEmpty()) {
                Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
                db.setDragView(row.snapshot(null, null));
                ClipboardContent cc = new ClipboardContent();
                cc.put(SERIALIZADO, row.getIndex());
                db.setContent(cc);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        row.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            row.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 0 0 0;");
            if (acceptable(db, row)) {
                row.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0; -fx-padding: 3 3 1 3");
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                event.consume();
            }
        });

        row.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            if (acceptable(db, row)) {
                int index = (Integer) db.getContent(SERIALIZADO);
                TreeItem item = árbol.getTreeItem(index);
                item.getParent().getChildren().remove(item);
                getTarget(row).getChildren().add(item);
                event.setDropCompleted(true);
                árbol.getSelectionModel().select(item);
                event.consume();
            }            
        });

        return row;
    }

    private boolean acceptable(Dragboard db, TreeTableRow<Map<String, Object>> row) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (db.hasContent(SERIALIZADO)) {
            int index = (Integer) db.getContent(SERIALIZADO);
            if (row.getIndex() != index) {
                TreeItem target = getTarget(row);
                TreeItem item = árbol.getTreeItem(index);
                result = !isParent(item, target);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private TreeItem getTarget(TreeTableRow<Map<String, Object>> row) {
        TreeItem target = árbol.getRoot();
        if (!row.isEmpty()) {
            target = row.getTreeItem();
        }
        return target;
    }

    private boolean isParent(TreeItem parent, TreeItem child) {
        boolean result = false;
        while (!result && child != null) {
            result = child.getParent() == parent;
            child = child.getParent();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void setupData() {
        TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> europe = createItem(raíz, "Europa", 742500000L);
        createItem(europe, "Alemania ", 81276000);
        createItem(europe, "Finlandia ", 67063000);
        createItem(europe, "Estonia ", 60963000);        
        TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> america = createItem(raíz, "América", 953700000L);
        createItem(america, "Argentina", 318900000L);
        createItem(america, "Chile", 122300000L); 
        createItem(america, "Méjico", 122300000L);
    }

    private TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> createItem(TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> parent, String región, long población) {
        TreeItem<Map<String, Object>> item = new TreeItem<>();
        Map<String, Object> value = new HashMap<>();
        value.put("región",  región);
        value.put("población", población);
        item.setValue(value);
        parent.getChildren().add(item);
        item.setExpanded(true);
        return item;
    }

protected void addColumn(String label, String dataIndex) {
        TreeTableColumn<Map<String, Object>, String> column = new TreeTableColumn<>(label);
        column.setPrefWidth(150);
        column.setCellValueFactory(
            (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map<String, Object>, String> param) -> {
                ObservableValue<String> result = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("");
                if (param.getValue().getValue() != null) {
                    result = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper("" + param.getValue().getValue().get(dataIndex));
                }
                return result;
            }
        );        
        árbol.getColumns().add(column);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado en la red este [ejemplo](https://brianyoung.blog/2018/08/23/javafx-treeview-drag-drop/) de un Drag & Drop en una lista en árbol que he adaptado para una tabla. La clase 'Persona' es en tu caso los datos de 'Región' y 'Población'

La clase con los datos mostrados en la tabla:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Persona implements Serializable {
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private LocalDate cumpleaños;

    public Persona(String nombre, String apellidos, LocalDate cumpleaños) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellidos;
        this.cumpleaños = cumpleaños;
    }   

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public LocalDate getCumpleaños() {
        return cumpleaños;
    }

    public void setCumpleaños(LocalDate cumpleaños) {
        this.cumpleaños = cumpleaños;
    }


}
```

La clase que rellena los datos:

```
import java.time.LocalDate; 
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;

public class MontarÍtems
{
    public static TreeItem<Persona> getModel()
    {
        Persona person1 = new Persona("David", "García", LocalDate.of(1942, 1, 8));     
        Persona person2 = new Persona("Luís", "Martínez", LocalDate.of(1958, 12, 17));
        Persona person3 = new Persona("Javier", "Gómez", LocalDate.of(1963, 3, 1));
        Persona person4 = new Persona("Pedro", "Gutiérrez", LocalDate.of(1971, 1, 12));
        Persona person5 = new Persona("Lorenzo", "López", LocalDate.of(1977, 4, 13));      
        Persona person6 = new Persona("Martina", "Sáez", LocalDate.of(1982, 5, 10));
        Persona person7 = new Persona("Maite", "Rojas", LocalDate.of(1983, 3, 21));
        Persona person8 = new Persona("Susana", "Martínez", LocalDate.of(1985, 6, 3));
        Persona person9 = new Persona("María", "López", LocalDate.of(1992, 8, 17));
        Persona person10 = new Persona("Teresa", "Estrada", LocalDate.of(1997, 5, 15));
        Persona person11 = new Persona("Javier", "Rojas", LocalDate.of(2008, 6, 3));
        Persona person12 = new Persona("Susana", "García", LocalDate.of(2010, 9, 13));
        Persona person13 = new Persona("Lorenzo", "Gómez", LocalDate.of(2011, 10, 11));

        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona6 = new TreeItem<>(person6);
        nodoPersona6.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(person11), new TreeItem<>(person12)); 
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona7 = new TreeItem<>(person7);
        nodoPersona7.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(person13));
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona2 = new TreeItem<>(person2);
        nodoPersona2.getChildren().addAll(nodoPersona6, new TreeItem<>(person8),nodoPersona7); 
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona3 = new TreeItem<>(person3);
        nodoPersona3.getChildren().addAll(new TreeItem<>(person9), new TreeItem<>(person10)); 
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona4 = new TreeItem<>(person4);
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoPersona5 = new TreeItem<>(person5); 
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoRaíz = new TreeItem<>(person1);
        nodoRaíz.getChildren().addAll(nodoPersona2, nodoPersona3, nodoPersona4, nodoPersona5);

        return nodoRaíz;
    }

    public static TreeTableColumn<Persona, Integer> getIdColumn()
    {
        TreeTableColumn<Persona, Integer> columnaId = new TreeTableColumn<>("Id");
        columnaId.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("personId"));
        return columnaId;
    }

    public static TreeTableColumn<Persona, String> getFirstNameColumn()
    {
        TreeTableColumn<Persona, String> columnaNombre = new TreeTableColumn<>("Nombre");
        columnaNombre.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("Nombre"));
        return columnaNombre;
    }

    public static TreeTableColumn<Persona, String> getLastNameColumn()
    {
        TreeTableColumn<Persona, String> columnaApellido = new TreeTableColumn<>("Apellido");
        columnaApellido.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("apellido"));
        return columnaApellido;
    }

    public static TreeTableColumn<Persona, LocalDate> getBirthDateColumn()
    {
        TreeTableColumn<Persona, LocalDate> birthDateCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Cumpleaños");
        birthDateCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("cumpleaños"));
        return birthDateCol;
    }
}
```

La clase que controla los acontecimientos:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DataFormat;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Factory implements 
    Callback<TreeTableView<Persona>, TreeTableRow<Persona>> {
    private static final DataFormat JAVA_FORMAT = 
            new DataFormat("application/x-java-serialized-object");

    private static final String SEÑAL = 
            "-fx-border-color: #eea82f; -fx-border-width: 0 0 2 0;"; 

    private TreeTableRow<Persona> dropZone;
    private TreeItem<Persona> draggedItem;

    @Override
    public TreeTableRow<Persona> call(TreeTableView<Persona> p) {
        TreeTableRow<Persona> row = new TreeTableRow<Persona>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Persona item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item == null) return;
            }
        };
         row.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> dragDetected (event, row, p));
         row.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> dragOver(event, row, p));
        return row;   
    };

    private void dragDetected
        (MouseEvent event, TreeTableRow<Persona> row, 
        TreeTableView<Persona> treeView) {

            draggedItem = row.getTreeItem();   

            if (draggedItem.getParent() == null) return;

            Dragboard db = row.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.put(JAVA_FORMAT, draggedItem.getValue());
            db.setContent(content);
            db.setDragView(row.snapshot(null, null));        

            event.consume();
    }

    private void dragOver(DragEvent event, TreeTableRow<Persona> row,
        TreeTableView<Persona> treeView) {

        if (!event.getDragboard().hasContent(JAVA_FORMAT)) return;

        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        if (!Objects.equals(dropZone, row)) {
            clearDropLocation();
            this.dropZone = row;
            dropZone.setStyle(SEÑAL);  // Dibuja línea
        }
    } 

    private void clearDropLocation() {
        if (dropZone != null) dropZone.setStyle(""); // Borra línea
    }

}
```

Y finalmente la clase principal:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TreeTableViewDND extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {       
        TreeItem<Persona> nodoRaíz = MontarÍtems.getModel();
        nodoRaíz.setExpanded(true);

        TreeTableView<Persona> treeTable = new TreeTableView<>(nodoRaíz);               
        treeTable.setRowFactory(new Factory());

        treeTable.setPrefWidth(400);

        treeTable.getColumns().add(MontarÍtems.getFirstNameColumn());
        treeTable.getColumns().add(MontarÍtems.getLastNameColumn());
        treeTable.getColumns().add(MontarÍtems.getBirthDateColumn());        

        VBox raíz = new VBox(treeTable); 
        Scene scene = new Scene(raíz);      
        stage.setScene(scene);      
        stage.show();
    }
}
```